# root user has no permission to edit environment file

Tags: permissions, vim

I recently got a new problem in my Ubuntu system. I have to change the contents of the /etc/environment file but it is not possible, even the root user has no permission to do that.

As you can see root has write permission here:

```
>> ls -lia /etc/environment 
262296 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 241 Oct  3 17:59 /etc/environment
```

It will not let me change the file.

```
>> sudo su
>> echo sample=1 >> /etc/environment
   operation not permitted: /etc/environment
```

There is no way to change the file even with an editor tool like vim and nano.

[image]

The outputs:

```
>> findmnt -T /etc/environment
TARGET SOURCE         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro


>> lsattr /etc/environment
----i---------e------- /etc/environment
```

Comment: There isn’t normally a root user setup in Ubuntu like there is in many other distributions. Consequently I’m not sure what `sudo su` will achieve and I don’t have a quick way to check at the moment. The output you have provided doesn’t show us which user you are acting as when you issue the commands. I suspect you may not have become root when you think you have. Have you tried `sudo nano /etc/environment`

Comment: ya I do it, and `sudo su` switches current session user to the root user

Comment: `EPERM 1 Operation not permitted` is different from `EACCES 13 Permission denied` and usually indicates something like a read-only volume rather than a simple unix permission bit issue

Comment: So how I can change my env variable inside `/etc/environment`

Comment: from my window experience, it would happen when the file is used or opened somewhere is this the same @steeldriver

Comment: Does it work with `sudo su -`? (note the `-` at the end) or maybe by just doing `sudoedit /path/to/file`?

Comment: @mattb I add an image, as you see it not editable as all,

Comment: Please add the output of `findmnt -T /etc/environment`

Comment: Also, please add the output of `lsattr /etc/environment`. The file _may_ have the "immutable" flag set.

Comment: @steeldriver Does it mean that mounting prohibits editing the file? if yes how to resolve it?

Comment: @k90mirzaei No, you need to mount a file system to get to the files on that file system in the first place, for reading, writing or whatever ;) You may want to read up on the differences between the organization of file systems in Windows and in Unix-like operating systems like Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the output of [lsattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lsattr), the file in question has the "immutable" attribute set (note the `i` in the list of attribute flags in the beginning of the output):

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

(from the [man page of `chattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr)).

The "immutable" attribute is one of a list of extended file attributes that are available on `ext` file systems (`ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4`).

You can set or unset those attributes with [chattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) like this

```
chattr +s /some/file # sets the 's' attribute
chattr -s /some/file # removes the 's' attribute
```

With some attributes, among them the `i` or "immutable" attribute, you need root privileges to set or remove them, so you'll do something like

```
sudo chattr +i /some/file
sudo chattr -i /some/file
```

From my experience, you don't run into those extended attributes very often. So I would recommend to look into why `/etc/environment` got the `i` attribute set in the first place. It doesn't have on my system ;)

Comment: Wow, It works thank you so much